# a non working single 10W MR16 in a recessed light (LED)

Tags: kitchens, dimmer-switch, light, transformer

One of the bulbs is not lighting up. I tried a new bulb and replaced the ceramic bulb holder and that did not help. What am I missing? Could it be a transformer that suddenly went bad? If that is the case what options do I have given that the transformer is buried in the ceiling. 
I have researched buying a separate transformer but it appears difficult to find a dimmable 10W transformer assuming I can get to the main wiring without ripping up the ceiling. Any ideas would be most helpful.
Also, do I need a dimmable transformer? Or will a constant work with a  dimmer switch?

Comment: a lot to unpack here. yes, the tranny could fail, leaving you few/no (easy) options. Dimming depends on the setup, how everything is wired and controlled; there's too many variations for us to pontificate.

Comment: If I can reach the power line is there a transformer that I can lay into the 4" gap in the ceiling? also is it necessary for the tranny to be Dimmable?

Comment: The inside trim package of most recessed lights is removeable. It is only held in the "can" mount by spring tension. Use your fingernails to grab the outside edge of the trim ring and pull down. It should slide right out of the can. From there, the driver for the LED light should be accessible without going into the ceiling.